# Wordpress add to cart is by default disabled need to be enabled

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce for my store. I have added custom add to cart button because of variable product using hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'spvs_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

function remeo_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;
 
    ?>
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
    <input type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button" value='<?php echo esc_html( "ADD TO BASKET" ); ?>'>
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
</div>
<?php
}
```

But when I inspect the code from the front-end of my store I got the add_to_cart button disabled.

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled">
    <input type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button disabled wc-variation-selection-needed" value="ADD TO BASKET">
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="834">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="834">
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0">
</div>
```

How do I enable the button? I tried not found any solution. I need this help. [My Store](http://buildingretrofit.co.uk/remeo/product/madagascar-vanilla-gelato-462ml/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because jQuery is applied to these default classes. With a variable product it is assumed that a selection takes place first, for example the quantity, a color..

Comment: Yeah, that's my solution, I used jquery on click variation and removed the classes. Thanks. I wasted my 4 hours. You are a genius. Thanks, thank you so much.